# Probability of a song being played in a 30 minute period?

Tags: probability

This is not a homework question, but something I am curious about because of a debate with my friend.

Lets say between three radio stations the song Counting Stars plays 12 times between the hours of 10am and 6pm. The song has an approximate run time of 4:20. What is the probability I will hear that song on one of those three stations in a 30 minute drive?

I tried solving the problem using the following logic. In those hours, that song played on the radio for a total of 51.96 minutes, or 10.8% of the time (51.96/480=.108). Therefore the probability of not hearing that song at any given time is 89.2%. A 30 minute time period can be divided into ~7 4.33 minute periods so the probability of not hearing that song in that time period is $.892^7 \approx.45$. Therefore the probability of hearing that song on a 30 minute drive is 55%.

I have a feeling that this logic is incorrect, though. Can anyone help me out?

Thanks.

Comment: Without reading and understanding your question. 6 minutes ago I heard a single song with a duration of 30 minutes:) coincidentally.

Comment: This question belongs on math SE.

Comment: Your solution would be correct if all stations composed their program of 4:20 min. slots (which align with your drive) and no two stations could play "Counting Stars" at the same time.
I think there is no definite answer if you can’t say how the random program scheduling works. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_%28probability%29).